# How to display only the appointments that the current logged in user has made instead of fetching up all the appointments from the database in Django

Tags: python, django

This the views.py file.
How can i display the appointments made by the current logged in user?

```
def user(request):
    client = Client.objects.all()
    appointments = Appointment.objects.all()

    context = {'appointments': appointments, 'client': client,
               }

    return render(request, 'users/user.html', context)
```

Here is my Models.py. I need to display the appointments by a user when they are logged in to their profile.

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = (
        ('Plumbing', 'Plumbing'),
        ('Electrical', 'Electrical'),
        ('Cleaning', 'Cleaning'),
    )
    STATUS = (
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
        ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(Client, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    worker = models.ForeignKey(Worker, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=CATEGORY)
    task_date = models.DateField(_("Task Date"), blank=True, null=True)
    task_location = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS)
    budget = models.FloatField(null=True)
    task_description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    task_image = models.ImageField(
        null=True, blank=True, help_text='Optional.')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of using `all()` in your query use `filter()`
`all()` gives you all the entries in the table.
do something like this:

```
appointments = Appointment.objects.filter(user = request.user)
```

the left side "user" inside the filter must be a column in the Appointment model/table. you can pass multiple parameters inside the filter.

Answer (score 0):

Yea it worked. but i had to create a one to one relatioship between appointment and User

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).